# How to add additional functionality to a data table in an HTML web page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, user-interface, frameworks

I have a large web project (Java/JSP/HTML) that has several data tables that need to be updated to have additional functionality.

Is there a framework/tool that will integrate cleanly into the existing project (i.e. I want to minimize the amount of work that needs to be done to achieve this cleanly) that supports all of the following?

- Sorting (including sorting from data still on the server, i.e. across
  multiple pages)
- Paging (including refreshing data from the server,
  i.e. ability to load each page from the server one at a time)
- Resizable columns
- Contained in a scrollable window (i.e. with and height can be fixed to a size smaller than the table and the user can scroll vertically and horizontally to see all of the data in the current page, bonus points if the headers are frozen and always appear)
- Drag and drop to reorder columns
- Easy to use/implement/integrate with existing
  projects

Comment: You can use  [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a website that could prove useful:  [datatables](https://datatables.net/)  I think that datatables looks like it would work well.  This datatables link could prove useful: [datatables custom column size](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/size_fluid.html).  I am assuming you are talking about data tables in general and not the website I found.  Here is a link that shows how to [resize](https://datatables.net/reference/event/responsive-resize) tables.  Here is a way to do it that people mentioned in the forums:  [How to make resizable data table?](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41106/how-to-configure-full-width-resizable-tables).

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap tables** is a better table than any other table.

https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table

It having below listed good **features**

- Created for Twitter Bootstrap (All versions supported)
- Responsive web design
- Scrollable Table with fixed headers
- Fully configurable
- Via data attributes
- Show/Hide columns
- Show/Hide headers
- Show/Hide footers
- Get data in JSON format using AJAX
- Simple column sorting with a click
- Format column
- Single or multiple row selection
- Powerful pagination
- Card view
- Detail view
- Localization
- Extensions

It having good documentation and able to integrate easily.

**Documentation**: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/

You can clarify your doubts with stackoverflow, it has large community and response:

**Stackoverflow Link** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-table

Sample demo here:

**Demo**: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this script to add sorting functionally to your table.

https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js

Also, you might use:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/displaytag/

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully useful, this [*solution for responsive tables with complex data*](http://gergeo.se/RWD-Table-Patterns/). Prticularly, the subsections *Options*, *Setup your table* and *Dynamic content* of [**How to use**](http://gergeo.se/RWD-Table-Patterns/#how-to-use) may show some features of your interest.